# React native Video compression

Tags: react-native, video-compression

Are there any react-native packages(npm) to compress videos? I want to compress the videos so that uploading these videos will take less time.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Shobbak/react-native-compressor](https://github.com/Shobbak/react-native-compressor) for a while now and it does seem to do the job.

Usage (per docs):

```js
import { Video } from 'react-native-compressor';

const result = await Video.compress(
  'file://path_of_file/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
  {
    compressionMethod: 'auto',
  },
  (progress) => {
    if (backgroundMode) {
      console.log('Compression Progress: ', progress);
    } else {
      setCompressingProgress(progress);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: When I checked the file size after compression I could not see the file size is reduced. It remained the same as the original file

Comment: @Anitta i'm having the same issue when i log "result". It seems like the success promise of "progress" is never logging for me either whether its in background mode or not. Anyone have thoughts? Or Anitta did you solve this issue?

Comment: I haven’t solved this issue